# StereoCalibration GUI doesn't start

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-calibration, stereo-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the message displayed in the console:

rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 right:=/optris/thermal_binary left:=/camera/rgb/image_rect_color left_camera:=/camera/rgb right_camera:=/optris
('Waiting for service', '/camera/rgb/set_camera_info', '...')
OK
('Waiting for service', '/optris/set_camera_info', '...')
OK

And nothig happens.
Mono calibration worked well for both camera
camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/optris/thermal_binary camera:=/optris
camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/rgb/image_rect_color camera:=/camera/rgb

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260119/stereocalibration-gui-doesn%27t-start./) by [RaduM17](https://answers.ros.org/users/30138/radum17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
Stereo calibration for separate cameras requires that the two cameras are synchronised. Are the timestamps of the messages from each camera the same?

**Comment by [RaduM17](https://answers.ros.org/users/30138/radum17/) on 2017-04-25**:
They are synchronised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was also getting a blank gui until I tried with the --approximate argument.  Try using
--approximate=0.1 or 0.3
along with your command.

---

Originally posted by [naveenT1010](https://answers.ros.org/users/30447/naveent1010/) with karma: 63 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0